# Traditional processing is deprecated

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I am trying launch my gazebo project with: "roslaunch spider1_gazebo spider1_gazebo.launch"
I have the following problem:

```
Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/jade/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 61, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 967, in main
    out.write(doc.toprettyxml(indent='  '))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 1382: ordinal not in range(128)
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/jade/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/d46/catkin_spider/src/spider1/spider1_description/urdf/spider1.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find spider1_description)/urdf/spider1.urdf.xacro'" name="robot_description"/>
```

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

When I run:  `rosrun xacro xacro --inorder spider1.urdf.xacro > spider1.urdf`

It show the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/xacro/xacro", line 33, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 967, in main
    out.write(doc.toprettyxml(indent='  '))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 1646: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the solution to this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214432/traditional-processing-is-deprecated.../) by [tachyon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23322/tachyon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-24**:
There seems to be a problem with encoding a  character ;-)

Please add the respective file (or at least the relevant part), otherwise we cannot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty sure that the *Traditional processing is deprecated [..]* warning does not have anything to do with the actual problem, which is that `f3` is a unicode character, which cannot be encoded in an ASCII range. The `xacro` most likely either declares an ASCII encoding in its [xml declaration](https://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml), or is missing a declaration all together and the default is to assume ASCII.

In any case, look at 'position 1646': there should be an 'ó' there (according to [this](http://www.codetable.net/hex/f3) site anyway). Remove it (or change the file to at least `utf-8`) and it should solve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tachyon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23322/tachyon/) on 2015-07-30**:
Thank you very much. I removed the character from the code - it was in the comment section - and now it works.
Thanks again!